# Inconsistent reSt rendering with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the following reSt markup

```
==================  =====================
**\\v**              vertical tab
**\\\\**             backslash
**\\'**              single quote
**\\"**              double quote
**\\?**              question mark
==================  =====================
```

which renders like *dead link* with the online editor *dead link*. However Sphinx renders it like *dead link* (note the missing backslashes on 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows). Why is this happening? How can I get the result of online editor with Sphinx?

**Note:** *imgur is banned in my country, that's why I have to give outside links to images.*

I'm using Python 3.7.5 from python.org on Windows 10, Sphinx 2.2.1 installed with pip.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Maybe it was a bad copy-paste? I get what you get in the first example, with everything properly escaped.

I would suggest however to use inline literals (double backticks) instead of `**` because that is what you are literally using.

```
==================  =====================
``\v``              vertical tab
``\\``              backslash
``\'``              single quote
``\"``              double quote
``\?``              question mark
==================  =====================
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that SmartQuotes, which is enabled by default, is causing the problem. Disable SmartQuotes and the markup above works as intended.

```py
# add the following line to conf.py
smartquotes = False
```